# A sharp in URL parameter

Tags: web-services, url

If you can help me I will be very grateful.
My problem is i send a request via google chrome like that :

```
http://localhost:8080/Webservise/rest/getinfo?user=user1&pwd=rdd#en&sscc=009
```

and whene i test the url he return :

```
user = user1
pwd=rdd
sscc= null
```

Because the # is an special caracter
any proposition ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes `#` is a [*fragment identifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). To ensure its interpreted as part of a query string you must URL encode it (to %23) - You should be doing this as routine for all query string values.